# Why is Drupal Core not updating via composer?

Tags: 8, composer

We realized that our Drupal core version is outdated by two versions. We are currently running [8.5.3](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.5.3), but [8.5.5](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.5.5) has been released. Rather than updating directly two versions, we wanted to upgrade from 8.5.3 to [8.5.4](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.5.4) and then eventually from 8.5.4 to 8.5.5.

We tried the following but it didn't get updated.

```
composer update drupal/core:8.5.4 --with-dependencies
```

Message after running composer command

> Nothing to install or update

I ran this command in the directory outside of docroot in `C:\users\name\Sites\mysite\` which has the following folders

1. .git
2. config
3. docroot
4. drush
5. hooks
6. vendor

I also ran `composer why-not drupal/core:8.5.4` and had the following message returned.

> There is no installed package depending on "drupal/core" in versions
>   not matching 8.5.4

Comment: That is the correct command, did you run the command inside the Drupal root folder?

Comment: Along with confirming where you are running this, what is the output of `composer why-not drupal/core:8.5.4` ?

Comment: Bear in mind that this is expected behaviour unless you actually used Composer to install drupal/core in the first place (whether that was manually or via the drupal project or whatever). So if your composer.json doesn't contain "drupal/core" under "requirements", you need to update your core manually, or convert it to a "proper" Composer workflow

Comment: @NoSssweat I have updated the question to describe where i am running the command.

Comment: @Clive i checked the `composer.json` file and it has `"drupal/core": "^8.4"` under require.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After running `composer why-not drupal/core:8.5.4` and doing some more research on the error message, I came across [Upgrading from 8.5.0 to 8.5.1 using composer](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/upgrading-drupal/2018-03-29/upgrading-from-850-to-851-using-composer)

This command did the trick for me.

```
composer require drupal/core:8.5.4  webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --update-with-dependencies
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your composer.json... do you see drupal/core listed under "require" or "replace"? Make sure you move it under "require"

Comment: Yes, I saw this exact same thing the other day on a project so can confirm.

Comment: @bleen `"drupal/core": "^8.4"` is under require, but still having the issue.